# VBA find and replace whole words only

Tags: macros

How do I change this VBA code...

```
Selection.Replace What:="IL", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

So that it finds the WHOLE WORD "IL" ONLY???  I want it to remove IL, but it's removing letters from names like, Bill, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Change the LookAt:=xlPart to LookAt:=xlWhole.

Your code will become:

```
Selection.Replace What:="IL", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried this and it did not work :(

Comment: Can you tell me what doesn't work? Also, can you post an example of what a cell looks like? Because it sounds like there's more than just IL in the cell? In which case xlWhole indeed will not work. In that case you likely have to include a space in the search word. So `IL` becomes ` IL `.